# how to solve unable to start service exception

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I have a problem with my app which is an app to get news feed and this app has a widget which shows a notification by the number of the latest news added to the xml file.

Every thing was okay on api level 8 and the widget was working good , but when I changed the version of the eclipse and the api level to be api level 17 , the widget stopped !! and I got exceptions !!

The following are the two classes I used to update the widget :

1) MyWidgetProvider class :

```
package com.example.testfeeds;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

     private static final String LOG = "testwidgets";

      @Override
      public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
          int[] appWidgetIds) {

        Log.w(LOG, "onUpdate method called");
        // Get all ids
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
            MyWidgetProvider.class);
        int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

        // Build the intent to call the service
        Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
            UpdateWidgetService.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);

        // Update the widgets via the service
        context.startService(intent);
      }

}
```

2) UpdateWidgetService :

```
package com.example.testfeeds;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class UpdateWidgetService extends Service {

  public static int numberOfItems=0;



  //numberOfItems=0;
    private static  String LOG = "testwidgets";



    ArrayList<String> feedsPubDate;

      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
      public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Log.i(LOG, "Called");
        // Create some random data

        feedsPubDate=new ArrayList<String>(); 


        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this
            .getApplicationContext());

        int[] allWidgetIds = intent
            .getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),
            MyWidgetProvider.class);
        int[] allWidgetIds2 = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
        Log.w(LOG, "From Intent" + String.valueOf(allWidgetIds.length));
        Log.w(LOG, "Direct" + String.valueOf(allWidgetIds2.length));

        for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
          // Create some random data



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////       

          RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this
              .getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
              R.layout.widget_layout);

          Log.d("numberOfItems intially", String.valueOf(numberOfItems));

              try {
                numberOfItems=doTestFeed();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

          // Set the text
          remoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.title3,Color.WHITE);
          remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title3,"  "+
              String.valueOf(numberOfItems));

          Log.w(LOG, String.valueOf(numberOfItems));


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////          

          // Register an onClickListener
          Intent clickIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
              MyWidgetProvider.class);

          clickIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
          clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,
              allWidgetIds);

          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, clickIntent,
              PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
          remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.title3, pendingIntent);
          appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }
        stopSelf();

        super.onStart(intent, startId);
      }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    int doTestFeed() throws MalformedURLException, ParseException

    {  
        Log.d("msg"," in do test feed");

        InputStream is = null;
        int x = 0;

        URL myURL = new URL("http://yunn.yu.edu.jo/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=55&layout=blog&Itemid=104&format=feed&type=rss");
        try {
            URLConnection conn = myURL.openConnection();
             is = conn.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;

        try {
            pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();
                parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                parser.setInput(is, null);
                Log.d("msg","before making parsing");
                x=parseXML(parser);
                Log.d("msg","after making parsing");
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Log.d("msg"," done testing");
        return x;
    }


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private int parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,IOException, ParseException
    {

        Log.d("msg"," in parser");

        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        int getElement=0;
        String pubDate=null;






        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){

            String tagName = null;


            switch (eventType){

            //----------------------------------//
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT: 
                {
                    // do nothing
                }
                break;
           //----------------------------------//
             case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
             { tagName = parser.getName();
                 if ("item".equals(tagName)){
                      getElement=1;
                 } else if (getElement!=0){

                      if ("pubDate".equals(tagName)){
                         pubDate= parser.nextText();

                         feedsPubDate.add(pubDate);
                         Log.d("value",pubDate);
                     }
                 }
             }
                 break;                     
           //----------------------------------//
             case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
             { tagName = parser.getName();
                 if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("item") && getElement != 0){

                 }
             }
                 break;

          //----------------------------------//


            }// end-switch.


            eventType= parser.next();

        }// end-while.

        int i=0;

        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("tempData", 0);
        String dateStringA=sp.getString("recentPubDate", null);

        Log.d("oldest date",dateStringA);

        for(String s : feedsPubDate )

        {

        String dateStringB = feedsPubDate.get(i);
        SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, DD MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date dateA = parserSDF.parse(dateStringA);
        Date dateB = parserSDF.parse(dateStringB);
        if (dateA.compareTo(dateB) < 0) {


            Log.d("imp msg","one new item");

            numberOfItems++;
        }

        i++;

        }


        Log.d("update result", String.valueOf(numberOfItems));


      // Toast.makeText(GeneralNews.this,"The size of the list"+feedsTitles.size() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   return numberOfItems;

    } //end xmlParser method.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}
```

3) StackTrace :

```
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.testfeeds.UpdateWidgetService@410a33c8 with Intent { cmp=com.example.testfeeds/.UpdateWidgetService (has extras) }: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2673)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at com.example.testfeeds.UpdateWidgetService.doTestFeed(UpdateWidgetService.java:136)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at com.example.testfeeds.UpdateWidgetService.onStart(UpdateWidgetService.java:81)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2656)
09-02 09:41:08.476: E/AndroidRuntime(1606):     ... 10 more
09-02 09:41:13.295: E/Trace(2270): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: have u declared ur service in manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not update your UI directly... In your log the problem is **NetworkOnMainThreadException** ...

So you should use AsyncTask or you can use **IntentService** or You can use **Thread with Handler** class also...

And this error solves by Using **StrictMode.ThreadPolicy()** also..But it is not apply for lower version also..

Replace the code of **doTestFeed()** by an AsyncTask.
Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing Network from Main  thread of Service, change the network access to a background thread (Async Task) or use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

Note that [services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process. This means that, **if your service is going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to do that work**.

See [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) of Service

Answer (score 2):

call this function `doTestFeed();` from AsyncTask

Answer (score 1):

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Replace the code of`doTestFeed()` by an `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 1):

If you get NetworkMainThread Exception you are trying to make a network call in main thread.
you need to make a call using Async task (background process) don't do that in main thread.

Else add this piece of code after oncreate() method

```
             StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: don't mention it @Akari